# Calculating (something similar to) moving averages with grouped data in R?

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse, zoo

Let's say I want to calculate the past-7-days ratio between dep_delay and arr_delay for flights in nycflights13. I tried the following, but as soon as I put any function from zoo in the pipeline it seems to completely ungroup the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
library(zoo)

delay_rate <- flights %>% 
 group_by(year, month, day) %>%
 summarize(delay_rate = 
  (rollsumr(flights$dep_delay, k = 7, fill = NA)) / 
  (rollsumr(flights$arr_delay, k = 7, fill = NA)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. By writing `flights$` the code is telling it to override the grouping and use the original ungrouped vector.  Remove `flights$` .
2. `summarize` is used when one row per group is desired but here it appears we want a result having the same number of rows as the input so use `mutate` rather than `summarize`.
3. There are unneeded parentheses here and while they are not wrong it makes it harder to read.  When expressions are potentially ambiguous or rely on rules the reader may have to look up it is a good idea to use extra parentheses but that is not the situation here.
4. `ungroup` at the end so we are not left with a grouped data frame.
5. dplyr clobbers `lag` and `filter` in base R so it will conflict with many other packages.  Always exclude these in the `library` statement.  This does not affect the code here since neither of those are used but as a precaution I always do that.
6. Seems unnecessary to load all of the tidyverse when the code is only using dplyr and its dependencies.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))
library(nycflights13)
library(zoo)

delay_rate <- flights %>% 
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  mutate(delay_rate = rollsumr(dep_delay, k = 7, fill = NA) / 
    rollsumr(arr_delay, k = 7, fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup
```